# Making executable file from Ruby program

Tags: ruby

I wrote a program in Ruby but I want to make an executable file from my program in order to run it in any computers( that they don't have ruby).How can I make executable file?
thanks

Comment: You made an RoR web application to run on user's computers?

Comment: I am ruby programmar on RoR programmar

Comment: It might help if you mention what operating system you're wanting it to run on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use RubyScript2Exe

http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/

> .. it collects all necessary files to run your application on an other machine: the Ruby application, the Ruby interpreter and the Ruby runtime library (stripped down for your application)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this list of options given your needs:

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables.html

They all have their strengths and drawbacks.  NOTE: I have not used any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on my [rb2exe](https://github.com/loureirorg/rb2exe). It supports Rails and Gemfile.

```
gem install rb2exe

echo "puts 'Hello world'" > test.rb
rb2exe test.rb
./test
```

You can also check my detailed step-by-step how to, here:
http://www.learnwithdaniel.com/2016/08/ruby-to-portable-exe-app/